# Proguard: `NoSuchFieldError` despite field being in `seeds.txt`

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, proguard, android-proguard

I'm trying to apply proguard to an android app that uses a JNI library.
 When the app runs, I'm getting this crash:

```
Thread[24,tid=8563,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xb510a400,peer=0x12f57190,"Service Thread"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.my.package-1/lib/arm/nativeLibrary.so"
 No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "I" field "mNativeInstanceId" in class "Lcom/library/package/NativeDetector;" or its superclasses
   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:-2)
   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:428)
   at void java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:369)
   at void java.lang.System.loadLibrary(java.lang.String) (System.java:989)
   at void com.library.package.NativeDetector.<clinit>() (SourceFile:48)
   at com.library.package.DectorTypeA com.library.package.Detectors.createInstance() (SourceFile:63)
   at com.library.package.DectorTypeA com.library.package.imageAnalysis.DetectorProvider.a() (SourceFile:31)
   at com.library.package.DectorTypeA com.library.package.imageAnalysis.DetectorProvider.provideDetector() (SourceFile:24)
   at com.library.package.DectorTypeA com.library.package.myService.e() (SourceFile:205)
   at com.library.package.DectorTypeA com.library.package.myService.c(com.library.package.myService) (SourceFile:43)
   at void com.library.package.myService$2.run() (SourceFile:226)
```

The error message looks like `mNativeInstanceId` has been obfuscated.  However, the library module's `seeds.txt` has this line:

`com.library.package.NativeDetector: int mNativeInstanceId`

meaning it was not obfuscated.

How do I fix this crash?

`proguard-rules.pro` for the library module:

```
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,LocalVariableTable

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames,includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}


-keep class com.library.package.NativeDetector

-keepclassmembers class com.library.package.NativeDetector {
    private <fields>;
}
```

`NativeDetector.java`

```
class NativeDetector {

    private int mNativeInstanceId; //intialized in JNI code
    ...
}
```

Edit: I've also tried a proguard file with lines like this with no change in outcome:

```
-keep class com.om.library.package.NativeDetector {
    private <fields>;
}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting JNI to be able to load a private variable?

Comment: It works when proguard is disabled?  Though it's a library produced by a third party.  I say `private int mNativeInstanceId;` is initialized by JNI code because that's what the comments say.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know anything about proguard or JNI, it just seems strange to me that you expected another function to be able to directly affect a private variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing might be because you added the **proguard** rules only to the library module. These are not automatically picked up for the application unless you specify them as `consumerProguardFiles`.

Comment: The problem might be because you added these proguard rules only to the library module. These are not automatically picked up for the application unless you specify them as `consumerProguardFiles`.

Comment: That was what I was missing!  If you'd like to answer I will award the bounty when the waiting period is up. @tome